# JavaScript not working on Production locally and heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have searched for solutions for this issue and i have found that i have to run bundle exec rake assets:precompile before pushing to heroku inorder to make JavaScript working but its not working i don't know why. and the same for the local production

```
production.rb

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.precompile += %w( chartkick.js )
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require bootstrap
//= require demo1
//= require polyfills
//= require announcements
//= require wice_grid
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .
```

Update: it not working in development. it was working few minutes ago.. :|

Update 2: it worked in development after reordering my application.js to the following:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require demo1
//= require polyfills
//= require announcements
//= require wice_grid
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .
```

and still doesn't work in production

Comment: have you tried it locally in production-mode?

Answer (score 1):

You should set this:-

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: NOT working , i have changed it to true and re-compiled again and its not working

Comment: It is not working on  your local production? can you post the command you are running?

Comment: I did not understand the command you are running but it should be like this #RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Comment: do you mean for compiling ? i am using this `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` i thought you were asking about the server

Comment: i tried what you said not working also , and its not make a difference if i wrote like what you said or like what i said both are the same